# Protection of Energy Meter from 35KV spark

Tags: power-electronics, mains, esd, power-meter, power-measurement

I have been building a prototype of an energy meter for a project. One of the aims of the project is to make sure the energy meter can withstand a 35KV Spark applied to it.

I was wondering how this could be implemented..

Is is the merely the casing/enclosure of the energy meter that is required to provide this insulation? I realized that this can't be all since during the test, the spark is also applied to the input and output terminals of the meter.

What do the input and output sides of the circuit of the meter need to have to protect it from damage? And as a beginner, I'd be grateful if somebody could explain to me the purpose of this requirement. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is law in most countries that devices must withstand a specific ESD discharge for the class of product that it is. Basically, if it's visible to the discharge probe it gets hit. Your device has to withstand that discharge without failure. Usually sufficient input resistance or *transorbs* are added to anything the test authority can get at if it is appropriate for the circuitry. Whomever is taking care of the certification process needs to contact the appropriate authority to determine which tests you need to comply with.

Comment: @John918 you must also consider the impedance of the spark (source impedance), look at the human body model. The capacitor used for testing is in the pF range so its not that big of a spark. If your talking about a lightning bolt, nothing is going to withstand a spark that big. So specify the current\impedance limits of the "spark"

Comment: @Trevor, the following is the test requirement:
35 KV Test as per Application of abnormal voltage/frequency :

The accuracy of the meter should not be affected with the application of abnormal voltage/frequency such as spark   discharge of approximately 35KV in any of the following manner for total 10 minutes:
i) On any of the phases and neutral terminal
ii) On any connecting wires of the meter
iii) Voltage discharge with 10 mm spark gap
iv) At any place in load circuit
v)  Spark on meter body.

Comment: Trevor, and what rating of Transient Voltage Suppressors should I be going for. Or like @laptop2d suggests, will that depend on the impedance/current limits of the spark?

Comment: What is attached to the terminals? Will a spark on them fry something...

Comment: What is this and what standards are you testing it to? the standard should specify the testing procedure

Comment: @laptop2d The following is the document that specifies the requirements that the meter must meet. You can find the details of the 35KV test that I mentioned in the comment above on Pg.24 --                                                                                           


[link] (http://www.pgvcl.com/consumer/Solar_Rooftop/PG_HT%20SOLAR%20BIDIRECTIONAL%20Meter.pdf)

Comment: @Trevor I doubt that a spark on the terminal block of the meter (which is cast from Bakelite) should cause any significant physical damage. But the safety of the electronics on the PCB that are connected to the input and output terminals of the meter are a cause for concern.

Comment: Yup, well without knowing the schematics it's hard to help you. It really depends on the individual signal.

Comment: Given these Power Meters get their power from the 117VAC line, those "power supply" circuit elements gotta withstand the 35KV. The way to survive is to ensure the ENTIRE POWERMETER moves up and down with the 35KV.